# Display custom field from parent page

Tags: php, wordpress

On a child page x,  i want to output a custom field from the parent page

```
<?php the_field('imagecategory'); ?>
```

The child page can also have this field (but i dont want to grab that)

so what i want is: 
On the child page,  grab the parent page id. And for that specific page show the output of the code

```
<?php the_field('imagecategory'); ?>
```

I asume i need to grab the parent id with $post->post_parent;,  but i got no idea how to tell the code to grab that custom field for that specific page :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently you are using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin right? If yes, you must to get your custom page where you set your custom field before to show it on a different page, something like this:

```
<?php $mypage = get_page_by_title('my page'); ?>
<p><?php the_field('custom_field', $mypage); ?></p>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You are 100% correct :), i was indeed using ACF (which is awesome, i just suck in php XD) and your answer solved it perfectly  (can't accept the answer for another 3min, will do so when i can)

Comment: I'm glad that's helped you :-)